# Is there a JS event that occurs when the user selects a file from a file field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know if there is an event that I can call a JS function with that occurs when the user has selected a file for a file field. Or is there something similar?

What I am trying to do is append the name of the file to the page once the user has selected the file, thanks.

Comment: when a user selects a file, the file input "changes".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when a user selects a file, the file input "changes", so you'll want to use the `change` event.

```
$("#myinput").on("change",function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VeGpS/